# Phonegap Build With Java Native File

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to PhoneGap and mobile Paypal. I tried https://github.com/azicchetti/MECLPayPalPlugin plugin in my PhoneGap app and works fine with emulator.

Now i want to send to PhoneGap Build for testing in real phone. But according to Phonegap Build doc, our app will most likely fail to compile if we upload native file like .java. 
So, how to change the Paypal server to live and app id in this plugin when i need to publish my app ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap build only allows the html5, css files. as you mentioned .java files are not supported. Hence if you want to build your android app, you would need to build it in eclipse and then it would package your html code with the paypal plugin as well.

Download phonegap libraries from [here](http://phonegap.com/download)

Included with it is the sample project and that can guide you as well on the structure of android and rest you can lookup [here for the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

define the plugin in the plugins.xml file, as shown in the sample below.

```
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/cordova/plugins">
            <plugin name="ChildBrowser"
                value="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/android/ChildBrowser.java"
                target-dir="src/com/phonegap/plugins/childBrowser" />
```

Here is one of my plugins.xml file for your reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
id="com.phonegap.plugins.childbrowser"
version="3.0.4">

<name>Child Browser</name>

<asset src="www/childbrowser.js" target="childbrowser.js" />
<asset src="www/childbrowser" target="childbrowser" />

<!-- android -->
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
        <activity android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </config-file>

    <!-- Cordova 1.5 - 1.9 -->
    <config-file target="res/xml/plugins.xml" parent="/plugins">
        <plugin name="ChildBrowser"
            value="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
    </config-file>

    <!-- Cordova 2.0.0 -->
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/cordova/plugins">
        <plugin name="ChildBrowser"
            value="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/ChildBrowser.java"
            target-dir="src/com/phonegap/plugins/childBrowser" />
</platform>
<!-- ios -->
<platform name="ios">
    <plugins-plist key="ChildBrowser"
                string="ChildBrowserCommand" />

    <resource-file src="ChildBrowser.bundle" />
    <resource-file src="ChildBrowserViewController.xib" />

    <header-file src="ChildBrowserCommand.h" />
    <header-file src="ChildBrowserViewController.h" />

    <source-file src="ChildBrowserCommand.m" />
    <source-file src="ChildBrowserViewController.m" />
</platform>
```

**One more things to add** 
include your plugin in the config.xml file

```
<plugin name="MECLPayPalPlugin" value="com.phonegap.plugins.paypal.MECLPayPalPlugin"/>
```

**If you do not have the plugins.xml file currently in your project create it under res/xml/plugins.xml**

Comment: Hi Diberted, thanks for your answer. I tried all those step you mentioned and it works fine if i don't implement the MECL plugin. But, now i need it and need to change the PayPal environment to LIVE, but according to the plugin instructions, i need to change it in the java file. So how PhoneGap will know if i don't include the java file?

Comment: in the project that you created, include the .java file provided by the plugin, there is a plugins.xml file that is part of the project and you would need to define your plugin there. look at the answer ( i have added the sample)

Comment: i am not sure if you would really have to make an entry in the config.xml but just incase i also added that above.

Comment: Yes, i have define all plugins in config.xml file and childbrowser is works fine in my app. Now, the problem is with the MECL plugin (this plugin is not in the list https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android) but in here (https://github.com/azicchetti/MECLPayPalPlugin). I unzipped the .apk file which i sent to PhoneGap Build, i can find childbrowser.js  which added by PhoneGap Build, but i can't find the MECL PayPal plugin, does this mean that PhoneGap does not support for this plugin or anything i miss out? Sorry, may be i'm a bit confuse.

Comment: it is possible that the plugin listed under phonegap-plugins (PayPalPlugin) is created by phonegap team and it might not be the same as MECLPlugin. The plugins that are listed in the phonegap-plugins site can be automatically referenced when using build.phonegap.com, but not any other 3rd party plugin. If you want to use your MECL plugin then you would need to build the apk on your own (not by phonegap build).

Comment: i have looked at the PayPalPlugin and MECL plugin and they both are different and seems you can automatically reference the PayPalPlugin using the phonegap build.

Comment: Ya, both of them are different and offered by PayPal. PayPalPlugin listed in phonegap-plugins is using MPL approach while the one im trying to use is MECL. Looks like i have to find another way to do it as MPL approach is not suitable for my app. Thanks for your info.=)

Comment: the only way i can see you can solve your issue is by not using the phonegap build website. phonegap build makes things easier but has only limited functionality, for advanced user (such as for your case) you would need to build using the android way.

Comment: Hi, i may try to build a signed apk file myself like what you suggest. But, not sure will it works without PhoneGap Build. Thanks!

Comment: if you build the apk using eclipse then you would not need phonegap build anymore..

Comment: Sorry, i mean not sure my app will works with PhoneGap framework if i build my apk without the PhoneGap Build. Because i still need to use the PhoneGap framework to build my app.

Comment: you can still build your application with phonegap framework. There are two ways of creating an application with phonegap, first way is the one that you are using.. second way is that you can download the phonegap sdk (which includes a sample project as well for android), that help you understand how it is working.